# How to change interface configuration from terminal

Tags: networking, interface

How do you change the IPv4 method in an interfaces from the terminal

[MAC address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfwUe.png)

[IPv4 Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1zyR.png)

My goal is to change IPv4 from `automatic DHCP` to `shared to other computers`

also in identity section I want to change the cloned MAC address to Random

I want to do all of this from the terminal

I tried change the files in `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/system/network` but this either breaks the connection to the internet or does not work

The interface i would like to reconfigure is eth0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your OS? This answer applys to Ubuntu 20.04.

**IP address**

You can set the IP address temporarily (until the next reboot) from the terminal:

`ifconfig eth0 <your desired the IP address> netmask <the netmask of your network>`

Ex:
`ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0`

Or, permanently change the IP configuration in /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
**Warning**: the prefix number of spaces for each line is important!

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
     dhcp4: no
     addresses: [192.168.1.233/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

**MAC**

You can not change the MAC address. There are ways to hack/impersonate another mac.
In case you use a virtual machine you can change that in the hypervisor menu.